# DateTime in Data Extension is 4 hours later than entry data

Tags: marketing-cloud, timezone, localization

I've got a journey that uses data entry from Salesforce, specifically when a lead registers for an event an `Event Registrant` object is created. I am pulling in the `Event_Date_Time__c` and `RegistrationDateTime__c` fields to the DE. Somehow, the data put in the DE ends up being 4 hours later than the data in Salesforce. e.g.:

[image: idk!]

I can obviously just subtract 4 from the field within my email templates but that's going to be a nightmare to maintain. It just looks like the times are being converted to GMT. There's got to be a setting I've missed somewhere!

Edit: Testing for any weird stuff going on, this function correctly returns the current time in EDT as expected.

```
%%[
VAR @currentSystemTime 
SET @currentSystemTime = NOW() 
]
%%Local Time For User: %%=SystemDateToLocalDate(@currentSystemTime)=%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there is no official means of coercing data feeding into the extension using the local time zone. The solution I have come upon, that works, is as I feared and must be handled in each email template.

```
%%[ 
    var @correctedDate 
    set @correctedDate = DateAdd(Object__c:DateTime_Field__c,-4,"H") 
    set @formattedDate = FormatDate(@correctedDate, "l","","en-US") 
    set @formattedTime = FormatDate(@correctedDate, "","s","") 
]%%


%%=v(@formattedDate)=%%
%%=v(@formattedTime)=%%
```

Editing to add feedback from SFMC support:

> ...it seems like manually adapting that will be your best be, sorry it
>   doesn't work as you expected! As well as the Integration works,
>   somethings just don't translate between the 2 platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Marketing Cloud processes dates to CST.

You can use the [SystemDateToLocalDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm) Function to deal with this (assuming Salesforce is your local time).

eg,

Assuming these are captured in a field called `Date`,

```
%%=SystemDateToLocateDate(Date)=%%
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply this function at the DE level or will I need to set this up in each of my many templates? I'm also considering the fact that I have time-based wait steps that are based on these fields.

Comment: To do that, you would have to create another column in a de and use the OFFSET t-sql function calculate this.

Comment: So I've added the function to my template: `%%=FormatDate(SystemDatetoLocalDate(Object__c:Event_Date_Time__c), "", "s", "")=%%`. It's progress, but the time displayed is still two hours later than the date/time field dictates!

Comment: Is the time in your setting above correct i.e does it match the time on your wristwatch?